403 Forbidden in Laravel
Description:
Whenever I visit the URI '/storage/decode/hello' the 403 error is shown, but when I go to '/storage/decode' URI, then the code works perfectly fine.
Route::prefix('storage')->match(['GET', 'POST'], '{any?}', function (Request $request) {

    $requestedUri       = $request->getRequestUri();
    $requestedUri_array = explode('/', $requestedUri);
    $task               = $requestedUri_array[2];

    if ($request->isMethod('get')) {

        if ($task == 'decode') {
            if ( ! isset($requestedUri_array[3])) {
                return "Bro you are in wrong place.";
            }

            return "Yes bro right place to be";
        }

    }

    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {

        if ($task == 'encode') {
            if ( ! isset($requestedUri_array[3])) {
                dd(['success' => 'false', 'message' => 'Please provide valid data to store']);
            }
            $encryptedVal = encrypt($requestedUri_array[3]);
            dd($encryptedVal);
        } else {
            dd('Invalid URL');
        }

    }

});


Route::prefix('storage')->match(['GET', 'POST'], '{any?}', function (Request $request) {

})->where('any', '.*');

This accepts any number of URIs.
